# Ios safari php dynamic image not displayed

Tags: php, ios, image, safari

I have a php script that gereates image data and uses header() to pretend to be an image. Works great everywhere, except on ipad / iphone safari.

I think because safari does not recognize .php as a valid image type. Fair enough. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning the correct image mime type in your php script? E.g.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

Remember to put this line before you start writing out the image data.

If you are then I don't know why it wouldn't work (can you post a link to the image?) but another thing to try would be using mod rewrite in your apache .htaccess file to map a.jpg extension to your php script, so it can be accessed using a URL that looks like a regular image.

That would look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^images/([a-z0-9]+).jpg$ imagescript.php?name=$1
```

So accessing images/foo.jpg on your server would actually load imagescript.php.php?name=foo